# How to determine debug build from gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to switch String value for Debug and Release build in BuildConfig file:

```
 def api= "\"api\"";

        if (...){// What to set here to determine is build debug or not ?
            api= "\"api-debug\"";
        }


defaultConfig {
  ...
    buildConfigField "String", "API", "${api}"
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set multiple `buildConfigField`s in the scope of the `buildTypes` like so:

```
android {
    // ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "API", "api-debug"
        }
        // ...
    }    
}
```

For some more details see e.g. [this article](http://toastdroid.com/2014/03/28/customizing-your-build-with-gradle/).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by creating separate resource folders too. But if you want to achieve it in gradle file, then update your `build.gradle` by adding these lines to create separate strings for both builds

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            resValue "string", "api_string", "api-release\"
        }
        debug {
            ...
            resValue "string", "api_string", "api-debug\"
        }
    }
}
```

After adding these lines, build the project and you can get the string in java using `context.getString(R.string.api_string)` but please note that there should not be any string in your `strings.xml` with `api_string` name.